# how to set budget for each model training session and then to pause the model training if the budget is crossed?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, cost-management, azure-cost-calculation

is it possible to control the budget for each training session in azure ML.
Lets say I am training a model and before starting the run, I want to set a budget of X dollars. and if it crosses, then my model training should pause unless I increase the budget to X+Y dollars.

Once the budget is increased, then only model training should resume. Is there any raw rest HTTP API or SDK options to control this?

Answer (score 0):

Today, there is no way to control cost at the granularity of a job.

Here is what can be done today:

1. You can define quotas and usage both at the **subscription** and the **workspace** level (i.e. control which compute can be used) -- this is done in https://portal.azure.com
   [image]
2. You can set up budgets on the **resource group** level with Cost Management -- but these are just to control and alert and won't limit any jobs (meaning, that a resource group can exceed it's budget).
   [image]
3. You can set up a spending limit on the **subscription** level, but that shuts down most/all services that cost money, so not a great option either.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/spending-limit